# Wordpress url ingore permalinks setting

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

My WordPress site seems to ignore my permalink settings for example;

I have a page with this link:

```
https://mywebsite.com/hello-world/
```

but when I view it the path on the address bar changed to:

```
https://mywebsite.com/?q=/hello-world/
```

I have made default to my `.htaccess` file and turned off all plugins but the problem is still there.

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this something that has just started happening? Or have permalinks never worked? Is your site working apart from this?

Comment: I just installed the wordpress today, i dont really pay attention to the permalinks path except after i changed it. The site works fine just that the path structure is not like what i want.
could be any sort of 'cache'? i did cleared it tho

Comment: `?q=` is not really something WordPress uses. Does that still happen with all plugins disabled? How does the rest of your server config look like?

Comment: Did you run `$ curl -I https://mywebsite.com/hello-world/` from the terminal to check it's not a browser/extension issue? Also, did you check it from the default theme to verify it's not coming from a theme function?

Comment: I found the culprit. Apparently there is a setting on my hosting where i can change to run `PHP as FastCGI apache, FPM apache or FPM nginx.` FPM apache seems to caused the problem. I changed it to **FPM nginx** and the permalinks return to normal.
thanks @swissspidy for pointing out about the server config

Comment: @FabianMarz yes i have tried with other themes, no avail. fortunately i already manage to fix it :)